# Is there an R Function to make a funnel plot using P Values and Confidence Intervals Only?

Tags: r, statistics, metadata, analysis

Within my data I only have the confidence intervals, Odds Ratios and PValues and I would like to make a Funnel Plot to prove a false heterogeneity within my meta-analysis in R. But I can't seem to find the function to make this work... I have attached some example data so you can see what I am working with...

```
Article  Lower  Upper  OR  PValue   
debbie   1.5    1.8   1.67  0.0001
Michelle 1.25   1.67  1.45  0.025
Richard  0.02   1.08  0.9   0.009
```

Any help you be greatly appreciated, even if you can point me in the right direction...

I can find plenty of articles which mention how to do funnel plots in R using the funnel.plots function however, none will work with the data I have. So I am a little stuck.

Comment: For clarification, do you mean [this when you say funnel plot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/funnelR/vignettes/introduction.html)? Do you have the raw data that produced these CIs and p-values?

Answer (score 1):

If we take the natural log of the `Upper` and `Lower` variables, they should each be 1.96 standard errors from the log of the odds ratio. We can therefore calculate the standard error for each study.

It is possible to make a funnel plot with log odds on the y axis and the inverse of the calculated standard error on the x axis to produce a funnel plot.

With your own data set, there are only 3 points, so let's make a larger data set to demonstrate this. We will create a table with the same columns, based on sample data which should have an average odds ratio of 1:

```r
set.seed(1)

data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  n <- round(10^runif(1, 1, 4))
  dat <- data.frame(x = sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                    y = sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE))
  
  coefs <- summary(glm(y ~ x, family = binomial, data = dat))$coef
  
  data.frame(Article = as.character(i),
             Lower = round(exp(coefs[2, 1] - 1.96 * coefs[2, 2]), 2),
             Upper = round(exp(coefs[2, 1] + 1.96 * coefs[2, 2]), 2),
             OR = round(exp(coefs[2, 1]), 2),
             PValue = coefs[2, 4])
})) 

head(data)
#>   Article Lower Upper   OR    PValue
#> 1       1  0.58  4.22 1.56 0.3797660
#> 2       2  0.29  3.31 0.98 0.9764189
#> 3       3  0.90  1.28 1.07 0.4417953
#> 4       4  0.57  1.50 0.92 0.7421806
#> 5       5  0.56 17.33 3.11 0.1952396
#> 6       6  0.96  1.13 1.04 0.3525411
```

If we take the log of the odds ratio columns, and calculate the standard error, we can then plot the points in a funnel with 95% confidence intervals. Furthermore, we can color the points that have a p value of less than 0.05 to show these are outside our funnel:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(across(Lower:OR, log)) %>%
  mutate(se = (Upper-OR) /1.96) %>%
  ggplot(aes(1 / se, OR)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(PValue < 0.05, 'red', 'gray50'))) +
  geom_function(fun = ~ 1.96/(.x), linetype = 2, color = 'red3') +
  geom_function(fun = ~ -1.96/(.x), linetype = 2, color = 'red3') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-3, 3)) +
  labs(x = 'Inverse standard error', y = 'Log odds ratio') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: I have just given this method a go, it is close, but is turning out this error "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object 'y' not found" I don't suppose you know what this means?

Comment: @EveeJasmine do you have `library(tidyverse)` loaded?

Comment: I was pretty certain, but reloaded it to be sure - I got a different error now... Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found... still doesn't like 'y'

Comment: @EveeJasmine I don't know where `y` is coming from. It's not in my code or data. My code runs on your sample data. Is your real data different?

Comment: I think that the 'y' is coming from:                     
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE),
y = sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE)).  But my data is real data taken from articles but has the same information as above

Comment: @EveeJasmine but you don't need the top part of my code - that's just dummy data for the example. Have you tried just running the lower code block on your own data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251226/discussion-between-evee-jasmine-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: @EveeJasmine if you can include your own data in your question (perhaps using `dput(df)` where `df` is your own data, I could help you apply this to your own data set.